# Css relative url images not appearing

Tags: css, relative-path, relative-url

I have a problem with my icons "not showing up" on a web page, These icons are stored in the fonts folder respectively.

Below contains the snippet of my styles.css

styles.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

My file structure

[image]
How do I reference my files to ensure that my icons show up properly?
According to the example here, http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/
I use  "../../" as this will go to resources/fonts.
Am I wrong?

Any help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Simply use ../ or ~/ and not twice

Comment: have you tried just starting with / to indicate starting from the root and pathing from there?

Answer (score 0):

each ../ is used to go up one directory. You are currently in the css/ directory.
If you want to get to resources/fonts, you only need **one** ../ to get to resources, then you can enter fonts/

Comment: the fonts directory is at the same level as the resources directory, not a child of it

Comment: "I use "../../" as this will go to resources/fonts. ", so I was assuming he wanted to get into the fonts directory that IS a child of resources.(He has two fonts/ directories).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I changed my css to the one you have listed above. However, the icons are still not showing. Any idea why?